# Why Can't I Define the Height of an Inner Container?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

No matter what I do I can't seem to adjust the height of a nested Container in my flutter app. It always seems to inherit the height of the parent Container. Everything I read online said to wrap the inner container with a `Center()`. I tried this but still ended up with the same issue.

```
  final _recommendations = <String>["Embroidery", "Jewelry Making", "Tennis", "Hiking", "Disc Golf"];

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0, vertical: 16.0),
          height: 200,
        child: ListView.builder(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          itemCount: _recommendations.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Container(
              width: 150,
              height: 50,
              child: Card(
                color: Colors.blue,
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(_recommendations[index])
                )
              )
            );
          }
        )

      )
      );
```

Seems to me like the height of `ListView` is defined by its parent which is `Container`. So I expect `ListView` to have a height of 200. Then the height of `Card` should be defined by its parent container which gives a height of 50. However `Card` instead takes a height of 200...

Comment: try wrapping your parent container with `Expanded` or `Flexible` widget if that doesn't works then just do the same for ListView it should work

Comment: Wrapping with `Expanded` or `Flexible` didn't work...

Answer (score 0):

Usually, a ListView widget tries to fill all the available space given by the parent element, even when the list items would require less space. You can disable this feature using `shrinkWrap` parameter of `ListView` as follow:\

```
ListView.builder(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          itemCount: _recommendations.length,
          shrinkWrap:true,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Container(
              width: 150,
              height: 100,
              child: Card(
                color: Colors.blue,
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(_recommendations[index])
                )
              )
            );
          }
        )
```

Comment: Hmmm `shrinkWrap: true` didn't fix the issue:\